# Pandas: How to find percentage of group members type per subgroup?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

(*Data sample and attempts at the end of the question*)

With a dataframe such as this:

```
    Type    Class   Area    Decision
0   A       1       North   Yes
1   B       1       North   Yes
2   C       2       South   No
3   A       3       South   No
4   B       3       South   No
5   C       1       South   No
6   A       2       North   Yes
7   B       3       South   Yes
8   B       1       North   No
9   C       1       East    No
10  C       2       West    Yes
```

How can I find what percentage of each type `[A, B, C, D]` that belongs to each area `[North, South, East, West]`?

Desired output:

```
    North   South   East    West
A   0.66    0.33    0       0
B   0.5     0.5     0       0
C   0       0.5     0.25    0.25
```

My best attempt so far is:

```
df_attempt1= df.groupby(['Area', 'Type'])['Type'].aggregate('count').unstack().T
```

Which returns:

```
Area  East  North  South  West
Type                          
A      NaN    2.0    1.0   NaN
B      NaN    2.0    2.0   NaN
C      1.0    NaN    2.0   1.0
```

And I guess I can build on that by calculating sums in the margins and appending `0` for missing observations, but I'd really appreciate suggestions for more elegant approaches.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Type": {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", 3: "A", 4: "B", 5: "C", 6: "A", 7: "B", 8: "B", 9: "C", 10: "C"},
        "Class": {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 2},
        "Area": {0: "North", 1: "North", 2: "South", 3: "South", 4: "South", 5: "South", 6: "North", 7: "South", 8: "North", 9: "East", 10: "West"},
        "Decision": {0: "Yes", 1: "Yes", 2: "No", 3: "No", 4: "No", 5: "No", 6: "Yes", 7: "Yes", 8: "No", 9: "No", 10: "Yes"},
    }
)

dfg = df[['Area', 'Type']].groupby(['Area']).agg('count').unstack()

df_attempt1 = df.groupby(['Area', 'Type'])['Type'].aggregate('count').unstack().T
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the function [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#//apple_ref/Function/pandas.crosstab):

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['Type'], columns=df['Area'], normalize='index')
```

Output:

```
Area  East     North     South  West
Type                                
A     0.00  0.666667  0.333333  0.00
B     0.00  0.500000  0.500000  0.00
C     0.25  0.000000  0.500000  0.25
```

Answer (score 4):

You were quite close already. The following should do the trick:

```py
df.groupby('Type')['Area'].value_counts(normalize = True).unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```py
Area    East    North       South       West
Type                
A       0.00    0.666667    0.333333    0.00
B       0.00    0.500000    0.500000    0.00
C       0.25    0.000000    0.500000    0.25
```

If order matters, you can reorder the dataframe manipulating it's columns attribute

Comment: @MykolaZotko neat :)

Comment: I definitely did :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can go for [`value_counts(normalize = True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
>>> df.groupby('Type')['Area'].value_counts(normalize = True).unstack().fillna(0)
Area  East     North     South  West
Type                                
A     0.00  0.666667  0.333333  0.00
B     0.00  0.500000  0.500000  0.00
C     0.25  0.000000  0.500000  0.25
```

Comment: Neat, didn't know about the `normalize` argument :-)

Comment: @LukasThaler there's a saying, Pandas has everything you will ever need ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([r.split() for r in '''Index Type    Class   Area    Decision
0   A       1       North   Yes
1   B       1       North   Yes
2   C       2       South   No
3   A       3       South   No
4   B       3       South   No
5   C       1       South   No
6   A       2       North   Yes
7   B       3       South   Yes
8   B       1       North   No
9   C       1       East    No
10  C       2       West    Yes'''.split('\n')])
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:]

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Class', index=['Type'], columns=['Area'], aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
table = table.div(table.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

We divide each column by the corresponding sum of the table rows.

It gives :

```
Area  East     North     South  West
Type                                
A     0.00  0.666667  0.333333  0.00
B     0.00  0.500000  0.500000  0.00
C     0.25  0.000000  0.500000  0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(
    df.groupby('Type')
    .apply(lambda x: x.groupby('Area').Class.count()).unstack(fill_value=0)
    .transform(lambda x: x/x.sum(), axis=1)
)
```